# How can I get private chat messages separated by listing in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I want to retrieve chat from this table which will be separated by the listing id. Here's my table:

```
id | listing_id | sender_id | receipient_id | message          | created_at

1  | 1          | 1         | 2             | Hi.              | 27-05-2021 09:05PM
2  | 1          | 2         | 1             | Hi, how're you?  | 27-05-2021 09:07PM
3  | 2          | 1         | 2             | Another listing. | 27-05-2021 09:10PM
```

I want to retrieve results like this:

```
id | listing_id | sender_id | receipient_id | message          | created_at

2  | 1          | 2         | 1             | Hi, how're you?  | 27-05-2021 09:07PM
3  | 2          | 1         | 2             | Another listing. | 27-05-2021 09:10PM
```

Basically, there are 2 things happening:

1. Fetching the sender and recipient for a chat by the latest one (that's why the first 2 rows are grouped and only the 2nd is showing because it's the latest)
2. Grouping the chats based on the `listing_id` though the sender and recipient is the same

The `listing_id`: In that app, people can post their ads and when a user wants to inquire about the ad, he/she can initiate a chat. And the person who posted can see the chat grouped under the ad.

I want to know about the SQL query and in Laravel. So, can you please show me how to get this from MySQL? And can you show me the Laravel code to retrieve this result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All that your expected result does is exclude the first row from the result. It's not clear why you'd want to do that, and that isn't grouping of any kind either. Your request doesn't make a lot of sense...maybe double-check what you've written in case it's not what you really meant.

Comment: @ADyson oh, I've selected it by the latest row.

Comment: `I've selected it by the latest row`...you mean the latest from each sender I presume? and how are you defining that? Because the data you've shown doesn't have anything which would enable you to define the order (apart perhaps from the ID, but you may or may not able to rely on that for ordering, depending on certain factors). Don't you timestamp each message?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I understood. Since I'm not a DBA, it's harder for me to understand SQL. I just want to know about the strategy. I've researched for hours but failed.

Comment: Also how do you define "a chat"...is it simply where the same sender/recipient combination occurs in each row? That's hard to query for because the values are reversed depending on who sent. It might be better to have another ID to encompass that specific relationship. And what is the significance of "listing id"? It's not clear how it relates to a chat.

Comment: @ADyson The `listing_id`: In that app, people can post their ads and when a user wants to inquire about the ad, he/she can initiate a chat. And the person who posted can see the chat grouped under the ad.

Comment: Ok and what about the date/time thing I asked about?

Comment: P.s. you should update the question with such info as you just have, then it's clear for anyone trying to answer it, without digging through these comments for important snippets.

Comment: Yes, I always use date/time in my tables.

Comment: You should show it in the example then, it would be helpful for getting the "latest" message from each listing

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function chatPreviews()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PrivateMessage::class)->latestOfMany();
    }
}
```